# How to send predefined messages to specified discord channels at fixed intervals?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
from http.client import HTTPSConnection 
from sys import stderr 
from json import dumps 
from time import sleep 
 
header_data = { 
    "content-type": "application/json", 
    "user-agent": "discordapp.com", 
    "authorization": "IPlaceTokenHere", 
    "host": "discordapp.com", 
    "referer": "TheChannelUrlhere" 
} 
 
def get_connection(): 
    return HTTPSConnection("discordapp.com", 443) 
 
def send_message(conn, channel_id, message_data): 
    try: 
        conn.request("POST", f"/api/v6/channels/{channel_id}/messages", message_data, header_data) 
        resp = conn.getresponse() 
         
        if 199 < resp.status < 300: 
            print("Message sent...") 
            pass 
 
        else: 
            stderr.write(f"Received HTTP {resp.status}: {resp.reason}\n") 
            pass 
 
    except: 
        stderr.write("Failed to send_message\n") 
 
def main(): 
    message_data = { 
        "content": "Hello, world!", 
        "tts": "false", 
    } 
 
    send_message(get_connection(), "ChannelIDhere", dumps(message_data)) 
 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    while True:     # Infinite loop 
        main()      # Send the message 
        sleep(3600) # Wait an hour to repeat
```

I am doing this to send messages like 'Good morning' etc (hosted on my webserver). The thing is I want to add many channels(Since I own a lot of servers) with different messages. I am unable to figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass multiple channel IDs to the `send_message` function, loop through them and send a message

```py
def send_message(conn, message_data, *channel_ids):
    for channel_id in channel_ids:
        try: 
            conn.request("POST", f"/api/v6/channels/{channel_id}/messages", message_data, header_data) 
            resp = conn.getresponse() 
         
            if 199 < resp.status < 300: 
                print("Message sent...") 
               
            else: 
                stderr.write(f"Received HTTP {resp.status}: {resp.reason}\n")  
 
        except: 
            stderr.write("Failed to send_message\n")

def main():
    message_data = { 
        "content": "Hello, world!", 
        "tts": "false", 
    } 
 
    send_message(
        get_connection(), 
        dumps(message_data), 
        "CHANNEL ID 1",
        "CHANNEL ID 2",
        "CHANNEL ID 3"
    )
```

Note that now the channel ID's must be entered as the last arguments. Also I removed the unnecessary `pass` keyword in the `if` and `else` part as they're useless there. If you'd like to send the messages in different timestamps you should look at [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to functions things concurrently.

EDIT:

If you also want to send different messages per channel you can simply map the channel ID to a message in a dict

```py
def send_message(conn, channels): # You can also use kwargs
    for channel_id, message_data in channels.items():
        try: 
            conn.request("POST", f"/api/v6/channels/{channel_id}/messages", message_data, header_data) 
            resp = conn.getresponse() 
         
            if 199 < resp.status < 300: 
                print("Message sent...") 
               
            else: 
                stderr.write(f"Received HTTP {resp.status}: {resp.reason}\n")  
 
        except: 
            stderr.write("Failed to send_message\n")


def main():
    data = {
        "CHANNEL ID 1": json.dumps({"content": "message for channel 1", "tts": "false"}),
        "CHANNEL ID 2": json.dumps({"content": "message for channel 2", "tts": "false"}),
        "CHANNEL ID 3": json.dumps({"content": "message for channel 3", "tts": "false"})
    }

    send_message(get_connection(), data)
```

This can be improved a lot, I'll leave that to you.

Comment: What about messages? I want to customize my messages too for every channel.

Comment: Im guessing you could make a dictionary that maps the channel ID to a concrete message, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Hey won't this work? I will have the same code pasted again without the from and header data and interval but with different channel ID and message and keep doing for as many times as I want and set that interval at the end so that all those go out at that mentioned interval?

Comment: I am a JS guy, so my idea may seem silly as this is .Py . But is it possible?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question at all, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to send multiple messages to multiple channels at a fixed interval. In the above code of mine I can only send 1 message to one channel.

Comment: In the edit I made you can send different messages to multiple channels, there can be a small delay between sending messages but that's just the downside of using a for-loop instead of asyncio

Comment: Shouldn't I change the referer URL? Since that is of a particular channel, and I am mentioning different channel IDs? The channels are of different serves.

Comment: Failed to send message. Even if I give just one channel ID and a message using your snippet, I get 'Failed to send message'.

Comment: maybe if you provided the error I could help you somehow? the only details you're giving mt is "I get 'Failed to send message.'"

Comment: That's the only error output. Since that's what's been given

Comment: That's not the error, that's the output you're printing on the screen. The try/except block is catching the error

Comment: So I used except to catch the error, and here's the error: can't concat str to bytes. Request sent. Request sent.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! You need to send the body as a JSON string, not a python dict, let me edit

Comment: I see you imported `dumps`, just use `dumps` instead of the whole `json.dumps`. Next time please think a bit

Comment: Yeah I fixed that. The thing is, the message is sent only to the first two channels. I get: Message sent, request sent, request sent in my console. But the message is sent only to the first two channels.

Comment: That's really not an issue related with the code I provided, accept the answer if it helped. If you have any other questions feel free to ask a new one on the stack exchange network.

Comment: Discord accepts only 2 requests per second. That's the reason.

Comment: Don't think so, the ratelimit for sending messages is 5 requests per 5 seconds per channel, so there shouldn't be an issue with that

Comment: No there is. https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#:~:text=Rate%20Limiting,-This%20section%20is&text=Clients%20are%20allowed%20to%20send,have%20their%20API%20access%20revoked.